# autofill component height in flex column

Tags: css

I am making a Layout.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content{
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Be filled the rest part
  </div> 
</div>
```

**What I expect**

[image]

**Condition**

I don't want to use `calc()` in CSS because header's height could be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex-grow: 1;` to `.content`

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content{
  align-self: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Add this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Be filled the rest part
  </div> 
</div>
```